# SSL certificate for subdomain

Tags: ssl

I have a domain with a standard GoDaddy SSL certificate. It is only eligible for one domain or subdomain.

My subdomain is linked with another server and hosting provider.

Now I want to create a subdomain and need to secure connection as well.

I see two solutions:

1. Upgrade current SSL certificate to Wildcard or UCC as it suggested [here](https://www.godaddy.com/community/SSL-And-Security/adding-existing-SSL-paid-certificate-to-a-subdomain/td-p/5630)
2. Issue a new SSL certificate for subdomain. I thought of Letsencrypt. Previously I tried to do that using [sslforfree](https://www.sslforfree.com) I have updated txt file in DNS setting for my parent domain as that website suggest to verify certificate but that didn't help.

So I have two questions:

1. Is it possible to have different SSL authorities on domain and subdomain?
2. How can I install properly free SSL certificate for subdomain?

Just in case it can help - my original website is hosted on GoDaddy

Comment: FYI, backticks are only for formatting code -- not technical terms or company names unless they're actually software, a log fragment, etc. See [When should code formatting be used for non-code text?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254990/when-should-code-formatting-be-used-for-non-code-text) on [meta].

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thanks, I edited my question. Will notice this your advice in my further questions. Do you have any remarks consider question domain.

Comment: (1) Nothing obligates you to use the same CA for subdomains as is used for the parent; when your server hands a certificate to a client, that certificate is evaluated on its own, without trying to do a SSL negotiation with any server listening at a parent domain and comparing the CA.

Comment: (2) I haven't looked into free CAs offering wildcard certificates -- frankly, a question about selecting a service provider is usually going to be off-topic on StackOverflow; see #4 in the "some questions are still off-topic" list at https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic. Back in the day, we had a lot of people post questions for which their product/service/website was an answer as a form of advertising, hence the rules prohibiting questions for which the answer is an off-site service wholesale.

Comment: (3) Questions about how to install... well... *anything*... are usually questions about system administration more than software development, so there's typically a different StackExchange-network site that's a better fit (or which will already have a duplicate answered).

Comment: ...btw, one of the nice things about your free CAs is that if you can programmatically get a new certificate for each host (without needing to pay money, have humans do paperwork, etc) whenever it needs one, the need for wildcard certificates goes down quite a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you migrate from the expensive GoDaddy certificates to the free [LetsEncrypt](https://letsencrypt.org) certificates. If you install the [FreeSSL.tech ACME client](https://freessl.tech) on your website (it is PHP), you can fully automate certificate renewal. The client is just a set of PHP web pages that appear on your website. It has it's own user login system and includes all the tools you need to manage your certificates. It even interacts with cPanel automatically to install certs.

I completed this task for a GoDaddy website recently and it works exactly as advertised. The installation was easy, with well-written and illustrated instructions. Same for the set up. I needed about a half-hour to complete the task.

If you enable the daily cron job, then the client will check for expiring certificates and for sub-domains that are not yet certified. This will solve your problem of adding a sub-domain and not being able to apply the existing cert to that new domain. The FreeSSL client will simply issue a new cert for the new sub-domain. And if you don't want to wait for the cron job to run at midnight, then the client dashboard has a button to click that will issue a cert immediately.

Answer (score 0):

It is fine to have separate SSL for a subdomain. The usual headaches with GoDaddy are not present if you already have an SSL certificate.

Providing you are not going to have any more, it may be cheaper to keep these separate than have a wildcard.

It is just a financial decision.

However, if your domain name changes in the future, you can transfer the SSL certificates to the new name, having two will let you use one as "turnaround" space.